# Cube JS dashboard app failing to load dashboard

Tags: javascript, dashboard, cube.js

I'm trying to make a basic dashboard with cube.js (which I am new to). When clicking the "Add to Dashboard" button in the GUI for a chart, it comes up with an error saying that the dashboard app wasn't found in the "dashboard-app" directory. Pressing the "Fix" button doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there anything I can add to this directory to fix this problem?